# How to change the color of rich:orderingList control buttons

Tags: richfaces

can any one tell me how to apply css for rich faces buttons for example i want to change color of rich:orderingList control....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Look if Skin CSS classes are available to overwrite the buttons. Or, use facets to override the default buttons and then you can set any styling.

Comment: Thanks max,can u give me some example for that.

Comment: Look at the sample provided by @niksvp.

Answer (score 0):

if it is your `<rich-list>` and ordered then override

```
.rf-olst-itm{
 color: red;
}
```